# Сортировка каждого списка отдельно

Tags: python

Сделал выборочную сортировку, но проблема в том, что данный код сортирует весь массив по 1-ому числу, но не сортирует каждый массив отдельно. Как исправить?

```
def selection_sort(nums):  #Сортировка выборкой
    # Значение i соответствует кол-ву отсортированных значений
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        # Исходно считаем наименьшим первый элемент
        lowest_value_index = i
        # Этот цикл перебирает несортированные элементы
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[j] < nums[lowest_value_index]:
                lowest_value_index = j
        # Самый маленький элемент меняем с первым в списке
        nums[i], nums[lowest_value_index] = nums[lowest_value_index], nums[i]

# Проверяем, что оно работает
b = []
for i in range(20):
    b.append([random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(10)])
print('Массив без сортировки: ', b)
selection_sort(b)
print('Сортировка выборкой: ', b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сортировка применялась к спискам второго уровня:

```
def selection_sort(nums):  #Сортировка выборкой
    # Значение i соответствует кол-ву отсортированных значений
    for numlist in nums:
        for i in range(len(numlist)):
            # Исходно считаем наименьшим первый элемент
            lowest_value_index = i
            # Этот цикл перебирает несортированные элементы
            for j in range(i + 1, len(numlist)):
                if numlist[j] < numlist[lowest_value_index]:
                    lowest_value_index = j
            # Самый маленький элемент меняем с первым в списке
            numlist[i], numlist[lowest_value_index] = numlist[lowest_value_index], numlist[i]
```